# i want to use one same button to play and pause.First click I want to play it & second click I want to pause it

Tags: javascript, android

And when I click it again I want to play it. Here is my code but it's not working as when i click the button again and again is starts repeating the same audio again and again instead of pausing is. Please help me

```
Button button_attention = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        button_attention.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 player=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alarm_effect);
                {
                    if (player.isPlaying()){
                        player.stop();}
                    else {
                        player.start();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try `player.pause()` instead of `player.stop()` maybe ?

Comment: You are re-instancing the media player every time you click the button. Move the player=MediaPlayer.create.... line outside of the event handler and then reference it from within. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-defining the media player inside of the on-click handler each time that it is called, therefore it will not work. You need to move the definition outside of the on-click handler and then reference it from within.

```
//Move it to here
player=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alarm_effect);

Button button_attention = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    button_attention.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if (player.isPlaying()){
                    //This maybe should be pause.
                    player.stop();
                }
                else {
                    player.start();
                }
```

**EDIT:**
Further to your comment regarding how to use this for multiple tracks, you should do something like the following.

Implement a method, such as the following:

```
private void changeTrack(int resourceId){
    player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resourceId);
}
```

Simply call this method when you wish to change the track using:

```
changeTrack(R.raw.MEDIA_NAME);
```

Comment: Thankyou its working fine. But it is working only for one sound now if i want to implement this concept to more than one button?

Comment: Hi, if this is working can you please mark it as the answer, I will add to my answer now so that this will work with multiple sounds.

Comment: Edited my answer so now that you can change the track by calling the method.